# Error: Invalid bytes string given: 0x

Tags: web3js-v1.x

Contract code:

```
function getAddressDnaIds(address owner) external view returns(uint256[])
    {
        return addressDnaIds[owner];
}
```

Code causing the error:

```
var dna = await this.airdrop.methods.getAddressDnaIds(this.address)
      .call({ from: this.address })
```

Someone know what is the cause of this error or how to fix it?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `this.airdrop` isn't pointing to the right address on the right blockchain. (This type of error is common when `call`ing into a non-contract.)

Comment: I was suspecting this as well because there are duplicate contracts on mainnet. I will check on the testnet where this resides.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because both pieces of code (on-chain and off-chain) are insufficient for answering it, and are incomplete by themselves (cannot be compiled and/or executed).

Comment: The first comment actually answered it. Might want to leave the question until the error message is improved in web3.